# PHP form submitting to db with multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hullo :)

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
$things = array( 
  array('one'=>'red', 'two'=>'$85' , 'three'=>1),
  array('one'=>'green', 'two'=>'$35' , 'three'=>0),
  array('one'=>'blue', 'two'=>'$32' , 'three'=>0),
);
```

Various things are done with this array on my PHP page, including making a form with fields of names/IDs red, green and blue, like this:

```
<form>
  <?php foreach ($things as $row) { 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $row['one'] . '" id="' . $row['one'] . '" value="0" />'; 
  } ?>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, I want to put the $_REQUEST into a MySQL table with columns named after the field values, and this is where I'm having difficulty. This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, email, $fields_list) 
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$values_list')
```

"$fields_list" is just a comma-separated list of the field names (red, green, blue). "$values_list" is supposed to be a list of the $_REQUEST values and is constructed like this from "$colours":

```
$values_list = implode('\', \'', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry;
}, $colours));
```

What's in "$colours" is the issue. When I do this, it works:

```
$colours = array($_REQUEST["red"], $_REQUEST["green"], $_REQUEST["blue"]);
```

But I don't want to explicitly re-state the values in the array, as this is likely to change over time. I want to just have the array defined at the top of the page, and then have the rest of the functions work from that. So, I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$colour_list = implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return '$_REQUEST["'.$entry['one'].'"]';
}, $things));

$colours = array($colour_list);
```

If I var_dump this version of $colours, it's identical to the explicitly-stated version above.

Why doesn't it work? How can I make it work? Am I going about this the wrong way?

I think it has something to do with what order things are processed in - the PHP versus the REQUEST. I also think I am over-processing my arrays/variables, I have a feeling I can skip a step somewhere but am confused and can't work out where. Please help!

Thanks very much :)

Comment: Would $_REQUEST["red"] contain any value or you need to get from that array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think what you want is dynamically generate the insert query.

Here would be my solution :-

```
function insert_query($data){

            if(is_array($data)){
                foreach($data as $key=>$value){
                    $fields[] = '`'.$key.'`';
                    if(is_numeric($value)){
                       if(substr($value, 0, 1)==0)//checking for leading zero
                       {
                        $values[] = "'".$value."'"; 
                       }else{

                        $values[] = $value;
                       } 
                    }else{
                        $values[] = "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."'";  
                    }
                }
            return "(".implode(",",$fields).") VALUES(".implode(",",$values).")";       
            }
}




$_insert = $_REQUEST; //Security wise would not be a good idea

$_insert['name'] = $name;
$_insert['email'] = $email;

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name ".insert_query($_insert);
```

Comment: You know, I'm not sure why it hadn't occurred to me that I could use the $_REQUEST array without specifying values, that might solve my problem... let me have a play. Thanks.

Comment: if you are gonna use $_REQUEST as is, then may I suggest renaming your input as name="things[' . $row['one'] . ']". This way you can access $_REQUEST['things'] without other params interfering.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that now.

Comment: Fantastic that worked! Thanks very much for your help :) If I can ask one more thing, you mention using the $_REQUEST directly is not secure - if I add mysql_real_escape_string() around the request values, is that enough?

Comment: The reason I saw it isn't secure is let say you have a column called bank_credit and if you are using the $_REQUEST array "as is" then bad guy can just send a request $_REQUEST['bank_credit'] then it would added to db blindly. So the solution is to have a list of "expected" keys and only process those.

Comment: Are you still using mysql ?  It is depricated you should be using mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Yes, you can use mysqli_real_escape_string to sanitize the string.